# Asp.net Controls Work only after ctrl+f5

Tags: html, asp.net, ctrl

this is part of my codebehind about Asp.net Lable(For Example):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.Cookies["Email"].Value != null)
        {
            Lable1.text = Request.Cookies["Email"].Value;
            MyVariables.YesOrNo = true;                    
        }
        else
        {
            Lable1.text = "Not signedIn";
        }
    }
}
```

this code completely worked just if i press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>,but I like it automaticly work.
Note:I have putted my codebehined codes into !Page.IsPostBack   and Out of !Page.IsPostBack but my problem didn't resolve.
Thank u for your answers.

New Edit:
When clicking on Asp.net Button,at first it doesn't work.I mean i can't press it.but if press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> ,after page refreshing,I can press it.I Know this question is very odd but i can't find logical reason for it.I post link of text file that show what errors i have recieved in developer tools of Chrome browser.
https://1drv.ms/t/s!AmlJd3_lvGhXaYfUEC0sRp8uPcM

Comment: I don't understand your question... What controls do not work? And Control+F5 just refreshes the page with a forced browser cache refresh. It has nothing to do with the backend code.

Comment: See how I formatted the code in your question and it's much easier to read? Please do that in the future when you post a question. People will perceive your question better, they'll be more willing to answer, and it will be easier for them to understand your question so they can focus on giving you a high quality answer.